# Boolean always showing True for Marketing Cloud SQL Query

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, sql

I have a SQL query that is always returning true for my boolean field even though the data in SF is showing false. Incomplete_Runtime_Data__c is the boolean field, all other fields return correctly.

```
Select 
d.WelcomeEmailAddress__c as [EmailAddress],
d.Id as [DeviceId],
d.Name as [DeviceName],
p.Name as [ProductName],
c.FirstName as [FirstName],
d.ContactID__c as [ContactID],
r.Id as [RuntimeID],
r.Online__c as [Online],
r.Date__c as [Date],
r.Incomplete_Runtime_Data__c as [Incomplete_Runtime_Data]
From Runtime__c_Salesforce r with(nolock)
Left Join Device__c_Salesforce d with(nolock) on r.Device__c = d.id
Left Join Product2_Salesforce p with(nolock) on d.Product__c = p.id
Left Join Contact_Salesforce c with(nolock) on d.ContactID__c = c.Id
```

In the Data Extension, I have the field Incomplete_Runtime_Data marked as boolean and nullable.

Why would the data only show True when it should be False?

Answer (score 2):

In your data extension, do you have `Incomplete_Runtime_Data` set as a Boolean with a default value?

I would suggest doing some tests by creating Incomplete_Runtime_Data as a text field in the Data Extension and check what value gets passed across.

There can be discrepancies in the way SF stores a Boolean value and how a data extension handles a Boolean.

If you find that a Text value is returning differing text result e.g. ON,  then you can properly convert it to Boolean with a Case statement

```
Select 
d.WelcomeEmailAddress__c as [EmailAddress], 
d.Id as [DeviceId], 
d.Name as [DeviceName], 
p.Name as [ProductName], 
c.FirstName as [FirstName], 
d.ContactID__c as [ContactID], 
r.Id as [RuntimeID], 
r.Online__c as [Online], 
r.Date__c as [Date], 
case when r.Incomplete_Runtime_Data__c in ('yes','OK','on','True','TRUE') then 1 else 0 end As Incomplete_Runtime_Data
From Runtime__c_Salesforce r with(nolock) 
Left Join Device__c_Salesforce d with(nolock) on r.Device__c = d.id
Left Join Product2_Salesforce p with(nolock) on d.Product__c = p.id 
Left Join Contact_Salesforce c with(nolock) on d.ContactID__c = c.Id
```

Comment: I was able to change the data type to Text and see what values were being passed. Each record was recorded as 1 even though it should be either True or False. It never recorded a 0 value either. I decided instead to just move forward with the Text values instead as those were coming over correctly.